# How do you add grouped dataframes where only some groups match?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, addition

I have two dataframes. I've already grouped by three columns. I then summed by group.  Two simplified versions look as followed:

Dataframe 1:

| pitch_type | zone | description | 0 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CH | 1.0 | hit_by_pitch | 4 |
|  | 1.0 | ball | 3 |
|  | 2.0 | swinging_strike | 1 |
| CU | 2.0 | hit_by_pitch | 2 |

Dataframe 1:

| pitch type | zone | description | 0 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CH | 1.0 | ball | 3 |
|  | 3.0 | ball | 1 |
| CU | 2.0 | hit_by_pitch | 4 |

I want to add them together so the following is true:

1. matching group values are added together

   1. CH, 1.0, ball from the first dataframe is added with the value for CH, 1.0, ball in the second dataframe
2. groups without a match are still included in the resulting dataframe

   1. CH, 2.0, swinging_strike has a value of 2 in the resulting dataframe

the resulting dataframe would look like:

| pitch type | zone | description | 0 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CH | 1.0 | hit_by_pitch | 4 |
|  | 1.0 | ball | 6 |
|  | 2.0 | swinging_strike | 1 |
|  | 3.0 | ball | 1 |
| CU | 2.0 | hit_by_pitch | 6 |

I've had some trouble attempting this. My inclination is to use

df1.add(db2, fill_value = 0)

but I get a weird resulting dataframe where only some values from each dataframe are copied over. Could it be that I am using an incorrect axis or level, since my grouped dataframes have multiindices?

I appreciate any and all help. This has been driving me a tad banana sandwiches.

Comment: How woud look like the output you're looking for ? Can you add it to your question ?

Comment: @Timeless added the desired output

Answer (score 0):

You can use concat and then groupby:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
df = df.groupby(['pitch_type', 'zone', 'description']).sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you want to join the 2 dataframe, combine it, group by it and also sum it.
In here I assume your first DataFrame are

| pitch_type | zone | description | 0 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CH | 1.0 | hit_by_pitch | 4 |
| CH | 1.0 | ball | 3 |
| CH | 2.0 | swinging_strike | 1 |
| CU | 2.0 | hit_by_pitch | 2 |

second DataFrame are

| pitch_type | zone | description | 0 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CH | 1.0 | ball | 3 |
| CH | 3.0 | ball | 1 |
| CU | 2.0 | hit_by_pitch | 4 |

by using answer from the [Mattravel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20165221/mattravel)
give we can just use concat for joining 2 dataframe by following this code

```py
>>>import pandas as pd
>>>df1 = pd.DataFrame([["CH", 1.0, "hit_by_pitch", 4], 
["CH", 1.0, "ball", 3], 
["CH", 2.0, "swinging_strike", 1], 
["CU", 2.0 , "hit_by_pitch", 2]], columns=["pitch_type", "zone", "description", "0"])
>>>df2 = pd.DataFrame([["CH", 1.0, "ball", 3], 
["CH", 3.0, "ball", 1],
["CU", 2.0 , "hit_by_pitch", 4]], columns=["pitch_type", "zone", "description", "0"])
>>>df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True).sort_values(by=["pitch_type", "description"])
>>>print(df3.head(10))
```

with the result as

| pitch_type | zone | description | 0 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CH | 1.0 | ball | 3 |
| CH | 1.0 | ball | 3 |
| CH | 3.0 | ball | 1 |
| CH | 1.0 | hit_by_pitch | 4 |
| CH | 2.0 | swinging_strike | 1 |
| CU | 2.0 | hit_by_pitch | 2 |
| CU | 2.0 | hit_by_pitch | 4 |

After we concat 2 DataFrame, we need to group by it and sum it

```py
>>>df3 = df3.groupby(["pitch_type","zone", "description"]).sum().reset_index()
>>>print(df3)
```

as the result you get the

| pitch_type | zone | description | 0 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CH | 1.0 | ball | 6 |
| CH | 1.0 | hit_by_pitch | 4 |
| CH | 2.0 | swinging_strike | 1 |
| CH | 3.0 | ball | 1 |
| CU | 2.0 | hit_by_pitch | 6 |

Which is same with the result what you want.
I hope this answer can help you.